# Convert string to Int in DataSet

Tags: c#, xml, types, type-conversion, integer

Sorting does not work in dataGridView1 because when reading from XML the data is read in string format. (Instead of 13-4-3-3-2 I get 13-2-3-3-4)

```
 DataXML = new DataSet();
 FileStream fs = new FileStream(file_name, FileMode.Open);
 xml_read = new XmlTextReader(fs);
 DataXML.ReadXml(xml_read, XmlReadMode.Auto);
 MyDatatable = DataXML.Tables[0];

 foreach(DataRow row in DataXML.Tables[0].Rows)
 {
     row[3] = Convert.ToInt16(row[3]);
 }


 bindingSource1.DataMember = DataXML.Tables[0].ToString();
 bindingSource1.DataSource = DataXML.Tables[0];

 dataGridView1.DataSource = MyDatatable;
 dataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;
```

When I try to convert to int the problem does not go away.

Comment: The column in the DataTable is a string so after you convert to an integer is gets set back to a string.  I would add a new column to the datatable an then put the integer in the new column.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue you're encountering is related to how the data is being read and processed from XML before being displayed in the DataGridView.

You need to ensure that the data is correctly converted to numerical types before binding it to the DataGridView.

```
DataXML = new DataSet();
FileStream fs = new FileStream(file_name, FileMode.Open);
xml_read = new XmlTextReader(fs);
DataXML.ReadXml(xml_read, XmlReadMode.Auto);
MyDatatable = DataXML.Tables[0];

foreach(DataRow row in MyDatatable.Rows)
{

    row[3] = Convert.ToInt16(row[3]);
}

bindingSource1.DataMember = MyDatatable.TableName;
bindingSource1.DataSource = MyDatatable;

dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
dataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;
```

By converting the values in the MyDatatable directly and then setting the DataSource property of the DataGridView to a BindingSource linked to your DataTable, you ensure that the data is properly formatted before being displayed, which should resolve the sorting issue.

Comment: Still facing this issue (sorted: 13-2-3-3-4)